# What I'm doing wrong if I'm extending a class CreateXXXSteps.java with RestRequestClient.java?

Tags: java, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I've create a testing framework in which I crated this class RestRequestClient.java which have all comman methods such as sending a request, validating response, getAccessToken etc..

```
public class RestRequestClient(){

String someFiled;
String someFiledTwo;
.......
....
....
String filedN;

public RestRequestClient(){
 someDataHere....
 ......
 ......
 ......
}

protected String getAccessToken(){
 return token;
}

protected Response validateResponse(){
.......
.......

return response;
}
....more methods

}
```

Then inside test folder I created this class CreateSteps.java

```
public class CreateSteps extends RestRequestClient{

 @Then("I should get response as $statuCode")
 public void verifyResponse(int statusCode){
  validateResponse().then().statusCode(statusCode);

 }

}
```

Here I got a review comment that Rest class should not extend the Step classes, my question here is why? when My intention was clear while writing the Rest class that it's for common function why I can't extend it with Step class which can use the methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *shrug* Composition is a lot more flexible. Extension may or may not make sense.

Comment: In other words, you want to use  what's in your `Rest` class, but `Steps` *is not* semantically a `Rest`, if that makes sense. It's something that *uses* `Rest`.